# SSD (windows 10) not recognized when installing xubuntu 16.04, UEFI

Tags: xubuntu, uefi, ssd, windows-10, ideapad

Sincerely asking for you help.
I recently got myself this new notebook: Lenovo Ideapad 320S 39,6 cm (15,6 Zoll Full HD IPS Anti-Glare) Slim Notebook (Intel Core i5-7200U Dual-Core, 8GB RAM, 1TB HDD + 128GB SSD, Nvidia GeForce 920MX 2GB, Windows 10)
Win10 is installed on the SSD.
I wanted to install Xubuntu on the SSD, getting rid of windows. No dualboot intendet, sole Xubuntu (maybe Kubuntu) on SSD. Also tried Ubuntu 17.10 in the first place, same results.
Unfortunately, I had no idea about UEFI and it's problems before, so I just installed Xubuntu and maybe screwed something up. After that, I followed all kinds of instructions of German ubuntuusers, but the SSD simply does not show up in Xubuntu installation menu. Also, SSD does not show up in gparted in live mode. sudo apt-get purge dmraid did not help.

I'm still a complete noob when it comes to UEFI, so I won't do anything else on my own and sincerely ask for your help, so I don't make anything worse.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: You *need* to open UEFI settings and change the drive mode from RAID to AHCI. Important: If you want to keep Windows then first install AHCI drivers or you won't be able to boot Windows after changing the mode.

Comment: Thank you! Is there a way to do this outside of windows? Windows does not boot anymore, comment: inaccessible_boot_device

Comment: UEFI is what replaces the old BIOS. It has nothing to do with Windows or any other OS.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with my 320s just a few days ago, and what I did was:
- enter BIOS by pressing F2 when the Lenovo logo appears after powering up
- go to Configuration tab
- go to SATA Controller Mode and change it from "Intel RST mode" to "AHCI".

RST is seen as "RAID" and it doesn't work in this scenario.